# How can the $request_method parameter be changed in nginx for a proxy_pass directive?

Tags: rest, nginx

I need to alter the nginx `$request_method` variable under certain conditions when I hand off the request through a proxy_pass directive.

I was thinking of using something like the `map` directive:

```
        map $request_method $request_method {
            default $request_method;
            DELETE POST;
            PUT POST;
        }
```

But, there are 2 problems:

1. map directives are only allowed in the top level http block and can't be changed inside of a location directive.
2. this also gives me a *duplicate "request_method" variable* error from nginx.

How can I alter the `$request_method` for a proxy_pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a directive [`proxy_method`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_method).

You will need another variable declared via `map` (yes, at `server` level):

```
map $request_method $my_proxy_method {
  default $request_method;
  DELETE POST;
  PUT POST;
}
```

And then in your `location`:

```
proxy_method $my_proxy_method;
```

Note that Nginx variables are evaluated lazily, so if you have lots of other locations, `my_proxy_method` will be evaluted only for this one.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I wanted. It's a case of RTFM, but I just find the nginx docs impossible to understand.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg can't argue.